# Patching/Unpatching decorator using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-decorators

I am trying to patch a decorator. The testing framework that I am using is pytest. I am able to patch it successfully. However, the patch remains through out the test session, and thus I am not able to test the decorator itself.

Here is a sample code

**decorators.py**

```
def decorator(resolver):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("additional_value", <some_value>)
        return resolver(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

**patching the decorator**

```
patch('decorators.decorator', decorator_mock).start()
```

I have tried stopping the patch as well. But this doesn't seem to work either

```
@pytest.fixture
def patch_reset_database_alias(request):
    decorator_patch.stop()
    importlib.reload(decorators)

    def reset_patch():
        decorator_patch.start()

    request.addfinalizer(reset_patch)
```

I am not quite sure what is missing here, and how could I make it work.

Thanks